# Infopath 2010 & Captcha for public Sharepoint 2010 sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, captcha, infopath, infopath2010

I use Infopath 2010 to create forms for public Sharepoint 2010 sites and one of the requirements is to install a Captcha check for each form.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to use *Image Captcha*  in infopath forms but you can use *text Captcha* instead.
See the following link
http://textcaptcha.com/

I hope that help
Regards.

Comment: Thanks! If the other image Captcha doesn't work out, I will try this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I used this CAPTCHA Web service with my project and it's work correctly. check this http://distinctcaptcha.codeplex.com/